# Retransmission timeout for duplicate acknowledgement

Tags: tcp

Segment 1 is sent at t0.
Ack for segment 1 is received at t5.
Ack for segment 1 is recieved at t7.
Which Ack should I use to calculate Re-transmission Timeout?

Comment: from the last transmission phase

Comment: @romanPerekhest so should I consider second acknowledgement.

Comment: it's hard to guess without seeing the "full picture"